# Reading a sequence of JSON objects from a Stream

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have a project in C# where I need to parse a logfile. This logfile is comprised of a series of JSON objects, one for each log entry.

The file content looks something like this:

```
{"severity": 5, "message": "something happened", ...}{"severity: 1", "message": "something else happened", ...}...
```

Note that the entire file itself is not valid JSON, but is composed of a sequence of valid JSON strings without a separator character

I'm using the Newtonsoft json.NET library in the project already for unrelated things. 
I want to parse this file into a series of JObject values, which I can then convert to a class that represents the message structure.

I've looked at the [JsonTextReader](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextReader.htm) class but from what I can tell it's meant to be used to walk the tokens of a single JSON object, not a sequence of multiple objects.

Is there some way to deserialize a sequence of JSON objects with json.NET?

Comment: Not easily.  You usually can't take an invalid something and make a valid something out of it.   That said, back when JSON was in its infancy I wrote a JSON parser from scratch.  The spec is simple and it took mabey 4-5 hours.  It should be relatively simple for you to write your own tokenizer that finds the end of a valid fragment.

Comment: Ooooh!  Nice find!  Good job.

Comment: Yes, it seems that the trick to finding the answer is in asking the question the right way. Changing my search term from "sequence" to "stream" led me to the right answer.